# Simple ruby guard watcher

Tags: ruby, rubygems, guard

Is there a way to create a simple guard watch?  I want to run a rake task when a file changes in a specific directory and going through all of these steps is too much for this one off task.  https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Create-a-guard

I tried adding this in the Guardfile but it doesn't work.

```
guard :doc do
  watch(%r{^documentation})                       { "rake doc:build" }
end

watch("/documentation")                       { "rake doc:build" }
```

So do you know of a simple way to run a rake task when a file is updated with [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/)?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you running the `guard` daemon? Did you run `guard init` as described? You're using two different paths here -- one for `documentation` and one for `/documentation` -- and you probably don't have a directory `/documentation`. (Are you confident the paths are relative to the Rail's project root?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use [guard-rake](https://github.com/rubyist/guard-rake) to run a Rake task on a file modification.

A more generic solution is to use [guard-shell](https://github.com/hawx/guard-shell) to run any command line tool on a file modification.

More complex use cases should be solved by [creating your own guard plugin](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Create-a-guard). You don't even need to create a gem, since you can simply define them as inline guard as Avdi shows us in his [a Guardfile for Redis](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/15/a-guardfile-for-redis/) blog post.

When you want to share your Guard, just have a look at more advanced Guard plugins like [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/) or [guard-jasmine](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine) as examples.

Comment: Thanks guard-rake is what I was looking for.  I though the rake feature was baked into the guard gem.